# Append a .css file to an iframe so styles can be overrided

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

i am trying like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#muestraMotor').bind('mousedown',function(){
        var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
        cssLink.href = "../estilo/css/datepicker.css";  cssLink .rel = "stylesheet";  
        cssLink .type = "text/css";  
        frames['cboxIframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink); 
    });
})
```

where cboxIframe is the id of the iframe,

Firebug jumps:

> frames.cboxIframe is undefined
>   [Detener en este error] frames['cboxIframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);

-EDIT-

I try like this now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtRsvButtonGold').bind('mousedown',function(){
        var $head = $("iframe#cboxIframe").contents().find("head");                
        $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "http://sameDomain.com/css/datePicker.css", type: "text/css" }));

    });
});
```

No errors but i cant see the .css file with firebug (and of corse styles are not being applied)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to append a stylesheet to another site displayed in an iFrame, if so I would assume you are running into some cross domain security issues, and I'm not even sure what your trying to do is possible, but adding `document.domain = 'example.com'` to both sites would normally let the sites communicate thru JS, but then again only if both sites are hosted on the same top level domain, and I'm still not sure if it will let you change scripts in the head section of the site in the iFrame, I would probably think not, but not really sure ?

Comment: its in the same domain. but in this location i am trying to use it i need different styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the `id` to `frames` you need to pass the `name` attribute of the frame (or its numeric index on the page)

Comment: but it has no name attribute :/

Comment: You can give it one yourself then. I think you can use `$(#the_id).attr('name', 'a_name')` or something like that (I'm not sure - its been a while since I used the jquery api)

Comment: that gave me no errors but i can't see the stylesheet or the applied styles